# Regex split on repeating character set

Tags: javascript, regex

```
'a121212b'.split( /(12)+/g )
```

yields

```
[ "a", "12", "b" ]
```

Why?  I'm trying to get it to split on the `121212`.  It's not exactly a complicated regex :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly what it is splitting on. It's also capturing the `12` since it's in parenthesis and returning the captured match. Use `?:` to say that you don't want capturing:

```
'a121212b'.split( /(?:12)+/g )
```

yields:

```
[ "a", "b" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to group it.

```
var a = 'a121212b'.split(/((12)+)/g);
alert(a[1]);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KbUXP/

Comment: I actually need to do ___exactly___ the opposite of that.  `'a121212b'.split(/((12)+)/g);` === `["a", "121212", "12", "b"]` :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the parens... I forgot that `replace` tacks in whatever you capture.

So `/(?:12)+/g` works

Comment: @micha -- Works fine.  You quoted the regex